# JSON on Android - serialization

Tags: android, json

is there any simple example for Android of using JSON in a serialization?

Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

We use the [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library for that. Serialization is as simple as calling

```
new Gson().toJson(obj)
```

And for deserialization,

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: deserialization :
MyClass myClass = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, MyClass.class);

Answer (score 28):

If you want to avoid using another library in your Android project just to (de)serialize JSON, you cau use following code as I do.

To serialize

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("key", "value");
// ...
// "serialize"
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("json", json.toString());
```

and to deserialize

```
Bundle bundle = getBundleFromIntentOrWhaterver();
JSONObject json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("json"));
    String key = json.getString("key");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is cool, but I can't imagine it working well for larger sets of complicated JSON

Comment: You're absolutely right, this is suitable for quite simple and reasonably small JSONs. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple library to (de)serialize JSON,compatible with android own json library.

```
// deserialize a java bean to json object 
JSONObject studentJson = JsonDeer.toJson(student);
// serialize a java bean from json object
Student student1 = JsonDeer.fromJson(studentJson,Student.class);
```

[library address](https://github.com/lazydeer/Json-Serializer)

Answer (score -1):

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results!=null) {
            try {
                Tec tec_m=new Tec();

                tec_m=new Gson().fromJson(results, Technician.class);

                ((AndroidActivity)activity).setData(tec_m);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```